# How to write multiple CONTINUEIF conditions in sql*loader control file?

Tags: oracle12c, sql-loader

I have a data file with multiple logical records forming a physical record.
I want to load the data into Oracle table using sqlldr.

I have used `CONTINUEIF` condition in control file, but some records are not being loaded as they have a different condition.

Table code

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(
ID INT,
VALUE VARCHAR2(4000)
)
```

Control file code

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE * "str '\n'"
CONTINUEIF NEXT PRESERVE (1:5) = '   at'
INTO TABLE TEST_TABLE
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
TRAILING NULLCOLS
(
ID,
VALUE CHAR(4000)
)
```

Data file

```
1~Message:
   at Sometext
   at Sometext
2~Message:
   at Sometext
3~Message:
Invalid Sometext
   at Sometext
4~Message:
Invalid Sometext
Invalid Sometext
   at Sometext
5~Message: Sometext
```

> Record 4: Rejected - Error on table TEST_TABLE, column ID. ORA-01722:
>   invalid number